# Framework Comparison and Overhead

Tags: performance, zend-framework, architecture

I am working on a Facebook game which is developed using Zend framework. Right now I don't have lots of traffic and already seen quite a large # of data usage / CPU time.

Actually, I'm not good at Zend. I good at coding from scratch for both PHP & JS.

so, I am curious about the performance of Zend framework. becuase I'm thinking about rebuilding the applciation using Zend as the backend to manage the data / session / logic. and use JS (native code or JQuery) for the front-end rendering UI and handle user action in the client side.

In between, use aJax to get data from Zend backend.. most likely REST.
Anyone has suggestion about this kind of structure? I want to cut down the server load by that and also easier to manage code, plus better user experience.

Appreciate if anyone has good idea. :)

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670003 (migrated from Super User).  It might be nice if there were a way for the author to pre-emptively move a question instead of posting a duplicate if they're not sure if it'll be closed as "Belongs on ...".  Though I guess that belongs on meta.stackoverflow and not as a comment here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(depending on how big the application is) I'd go for lightweight dispatcher and use of zend. Zend dispatch process is too complicated for simple things like facebook games and especialy for AJAX calls. That should lower your CPU usage. Data usage is not connected with using zend i guess...